# Cardboard Parameters

Tags: google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am developing a Browser Based Cardboard App which needs the following details of various cardboards:

1. Screen to lens distance
2. Inter-lens distance
3. Screen vertical alignment
4. Tray to lens-center distance
5. Distortion coefficients

For these cardboards:

1. Aura VR v2
2. LaminatedCardboardV1
3. Cardboard I/O 2015

Comment: This page ( https://vr.google.com/cardboard/viewerprofilegenerator/ ) generates profile by taking various inputs. Is there a page which provides the details of cardboard given a profile name?